i am not able to get session token in aws cli
I am running the below command in awc cli
aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:I am::<Account>:mfa/**** --token-code <MFA CODE>

every time I am getting this response
An error occurred (ExpiredToken) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is expired

can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

Check the AWS credentials that you are using when running aws sts get-session-token. They'll be in your environment variables or the default config/credentials files. Run aws sts get-caller-identity to see them.

when i run this command aws sts get-caller-identity it will give me the same error

It will, or it does? Regardless, the credentials you are using appear to have expired. For example if you run aws s3 ls, does it also result in ExpiredToken?

yes getting the same error

OK, well it sounds like you are using STS credentials when you invoke the awscli and those STS credentials have expired. Is it possible that you are calling get-session-token with your old credentials (now expired) that you got from a prior call to get-session-token? Do you have persistent IAM user credentials that will allow you to call get-session-token to get new, temporary credentials?

I am not sure about that, i am new in AWS so still learning, can you help me which step should I take ?

You can read about the various options to provide credentials here. Because you did not explicitly provide credentials on the command line when invoking the awscli, you are implicitly getting your credentials either from environment variables or the default credential profile. What process did you originally use to supply AWS credentials?

Since you are new to AWS, let's start with the basics...
On your own computer
If you are using the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) from your own computer, then it will need some AWS Credentials to be able to use your AWS Account.
You should:

Create an IAM User in the AWS management console and assign desired permissions
In the Security credentials tab of that user, select Create access key -- this will provide an Access Key and a Secret Key
On your computer, store those credentials by using the AWS CLI aws configure command -- it will ask for the Access Key and Secret Key and will store them in a ~/.aws/credentials file

You should then be able to use the AWS CLI to access your AWS Account (eg aws s3 ls to list S3 buckets).
On an Amazon EC2 instance
If you are running the AWS CLI (or any code) on an EC2 instance, then you should:

Create an IAM Role (instead of an IAM User) and assign desired permissions
Assign the IAM Role to your EC2 instance either at Launch time, or by using Actions/Security/Modify IAM Role

You should then be able to use the AWS CLI on the EC2 instance and it will have the permissions assigned to the IAM Role.
MFA Device
Your question shows this command:
aws sts get-session-token --serial-number arn:aws:iam::<Account>:mfa/**** --token-code <MFA CODE>

This is typically used when you want to use an IAM entity that is configured to require Multi-Factor Authentication. The command passes the MFA code that you observe on your device and returns a new set of temporary credentials that can be used to access AWS. If you are not using MFA, then you will not need to use this command.
